# Dynamic Response from Retrofit Json to Gson Android Kotlin/Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit

I have dynamic json format from rest API like this :

```
{
    "data": {
        "response_code": "success",
        "value": {
            "Table": [
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "username": "blahblah",
                    "password": "blahblah",
                    "role": 2,
                    "email": "blah@tes.com",
                    "tanggal_buat": "2019-01-01T00:00:00"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "meta": {
        "http_status": 200
    }
}
```

Object "value" has an object array name "Table". Table can contain value from my database dynamically depend on my query. So, Sometimes the json format will change for example :

```
{
    "data": {
        "response_code": "success",
        "value": {
            "Table": [
                {
                    "id_product": 44,
                    "product": "blahblah",
                    "lot": "blahblah",
                    "qty": 2,
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "meta": {
        "http_status": 200
    }
}
```

How to accept the json value and assign to gson directly with different subclass of "Table"

I try it in retrofit and using kotlin

```
override fun onResponse(call: Call<MainResp>, response: Response<MainResp>) {
                    mainResponse : MainResp = response.body()
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have the following class among others (using sth like http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/):

```
class Value {
    List<Table> tables;
}
```

The "Table" class here cannot be completely random!
You'll need to define the possible types of "Table" e.g. Table1, Table2... TableN.

Now you can update `Value` class with a generic type **T** instead of Table and write your custom type adapter:

```
class Value {
    List<T> tables;
}
```

One of the tutorials on how to write your own type adapter is [here](https://dzone.com/articles/deserialization-1).

Comment: thanks you, I just know about generic class T can be a parameter

class Data<T> {
    .....
}